# curl from shell: discard output file if transfer timed-out

Tags: shell, curl

Using curl from the shell, what is the best way to discard (or detect) files that are not completely downloaded because a timeout occurred? What I'm trying to do is:

```
curl -m 2 --compress -o "dest/#1" "http://url/{$list}"
```

When a timeout occurs, the log shows it, and the part of the file that was downloaded is saved to disk:

```
[4/13]: http://URL/123.jpg --> dest/123.jpg
 99 97984   99 97189    0     0  45469      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 62500
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 2000 milliseconds with 97189 bytes received
```

I'm trying to either get rid of the files that were not 100% downloaded, or have them listed to attempt a resume (-C flag), later.

Comment: Check the exit code `$?`.  If it's not zero, it implies an error.

Comment: i'm downloading several files at a time (so that it reuses the connection), and it can time-out for only one of them. I would need to relate the exit code to the right file.

Comment: Can't you put `curl` within a `for` loop thereby instructing it to fetch one file at a time instead of passing a URL list?  That'd enable you to check the return code for each URL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. According to the man page, curl won't reuse connections between separate curl invokes, and I'm trying to download over 50 files at a time. So, i would prefer not to use that solution unless there isn't any other possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I have found so far is to capture the stderr of the curl call, and parse it with a combination of perl and grep to get the output file names:

```
curl -m 2 -o "dest/#1" "http://url/{$list}" 2>curl.out
perl -pe 's/[\t\n ]+/ /g ; s/--> /\n/g' curl.out | grep -i "Curl: (28)" | perl -pe 's/ .*//g'
```